# best way to handle json from httpresponse android

Tags: java, android, json

I have used httpclient to call a restapi written in django. It returned the json output. My httpresponse variable stored it and later convert the reponse to string and then to json object, i think its lengthy though it is working . I am really new to java , can anybody advise me , what is the best alternative logic to the code below

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/ca/entry/?
            format=json&username=pragya");
    try {
        // Add your data
        //List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", pw.getText().toString()));
        //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            JSONObject meta = jsonObject.getJSONObject("meta");  
            String limit = meta.getString("limit");  
            Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, limit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("objects");

            String key = array.getJSONObject(0).getString("api_key");
            String uname = array.getJSONObject(0).getString("username");
            Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, uname + " " + key,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        //Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
});
```

the json is as follows

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [{"api_key": "c87391754b522d0c83b2c8b5e4c8cfd614559632deee70fdf1b48d470307e40e", "homeAddress": "kathmandu", "resource_uri": "/api/ca/entry/1/", "username": "sumit"}]}
```

Comment: you can use Gson google library to parse json easily.

Comment: To convert entity to string I have only online code..  String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library from google, it is perfect for these kind of tasks.

All you need to do is define a new class that contains fields with the names of the **keys** in the json object and then use Gson to parse the Json string directly into the object or vice versa.

So for example:

Json looks like this: `"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1`.

Java Class will be:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int limit;
    private int next;
    private int offset;
    private int previous;
    private int total_count;

public int getLimit() {
    return limit;
}
public void setLimit(int limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
}
public int getNext() {
    return next;
}
public void setNext(int next) {
    this.next = next;
}
public int getOffset() {
    return offset;
}
public void setOffset(int offset) {
    this.offset = offset;
}
public int getPrevious() {
    return previous;
}
public void setPrevious(int previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
}
public int getTotal_count() {
    return total_count;
}
public void setTotal_count(int total_count) {
    this.total_count = total_count;
}
}
```

And use Gson code like that:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
 MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class); // deserializes json into MyClass
```

Please note that the name of the class fields have to match exactly the name of the **keys** in the json string.

Answer (score 1):

Always perform lengthy non-UI task using `AsyncTask`. All the operations you described, fetching of json and parsing them, can be performed in `AsyncTask`. Write the entire code which you have currently written in `onClick` event and write it `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`.

Check the following for more details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html