# Get a JSON object from a HTTP response

Tags: java, android, json

I want to get a `JSON` object from a Http get response:

Here is my current code for the Http get:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
    HttpResponse response;
    String result = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);         
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(instream);
            // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
            System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + result);
            instream.close();
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                netState.setLogginDone(true);
            }

        }
        // Headers
        org.apache.http.Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(headers[i]);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the convertSteamToString function:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Right now I am just getting a string object. How can I get a JSON object back.

Comment: what are you getting in your result string?

Comment: and why are you using response.getEntity() twice?

Comment: To get a JSON object back shldnt the webserver you connect to send u a JSON back ? Does it do that ?

Comment: @Zapnologica check my answer . Also see agen451 answer

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The string that you get is just the JSON Object.toString(). It means that you get the JSON object, but in a String format.

If you are supposed to get a JSON Object you can just put:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: What if in case of HttpExchange ..?

Comment: @Renan Bandeira I am trying your code to convert my http response to a json object and I am getting this error 
`Error:(47, 50) java: incompatible types: java.lang.StringBuffer cannot be converted to java.util.Map`

Comment: @Karapapas can you show your code? My answer was in 2013. I would recommend you to use something as Retrofit and Gson/Jackson to deal with requests and Json serialization.

Comment: how can I do this same assignment in c#?

Answer (score 13):

Do this to get the JSON

```
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

More details here : [get json from HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129286/get-json-from-httpresponse)

Comment: that is a *String* not a JSON !

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes? This is just a `toString()` function - basically the exact same thing the OP is doing.

Comment: At least this gets rid of a lot of low level overhead code of the OP. See the post of @Catalin Pirvu below for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 12):

This is not the exact answer for your question, but this may help you

```
public class JsonParser {

    private static DefaultHttpClient httpClient = ConnectionManager.getClient();

    public static List<Club> getNearestClubs(double lat, double lon) {
        // YOUR URL GOES HERE
        String getUrl = Constants.BASE_URL + String.format("getClosestClubs?lat=%f&lon=%f", lat, lon);

        List<Club> ret = new ArrayList<Club>();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(getUrl);
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

            // CONVERT RESPONSE TO STRING
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON ARRAY
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

            // ITERATE THROUGH AND RETRIEVE CLUB FIELDS
            int n = ja.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                // GET INDIVIDUAL JSON OBJECT FROM JSON ARRAY
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                // RETRIEVE EACH JSON OBJECT'S FIELDS
                long id = jo.getLong("id");
                String name = jo.getString("name");
                String address = jo.getString("address");
                String country = jo.getString("country");
                String zip = jo.getString("zip");
                double clat = jo.getDouble("lat");
                double clon = jo.getDouble("lon");
                String url = jo.getString("url");
                String number = jo.getString("number");

                // CONVERT DATA FIELDS TO CLUB OBJECT
                Club c = new Club(id, name, address, country, zip, clat, clon, url, number);
                ret.add(c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // RETURN LIST OF CLUBS
        return ret;
    }

}
Again, it’s relatively straight forward, but the methods I’ll make special note of are:

JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
long id = jo.getLong("id");
String name = jo.getString("name");
double clat = jo.getDouble("lat");
```

Answer (score 10):

Without a look at your exact JSON output, it's hard to give you some working code. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial is very useful, but you could use something along the lines of:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("yourJsonString");
```

Then you can retrieve from this json object using:

```
String value = jsonObj.getString("yourKey");
```

Comment: Very nice tutorial. "In general all the JSON nodes will start with a square bracket or with a curly bracket. The difference between [ and { is, the square bracket ([) represents starting of an JSONArray node whereas curly bracket ({) represents JSONObject. So while accessing these nodes we need to call appropriate method to access the data.

If your JSON node starts with [, then we should use getJSONArray() method. Same as if the node starts with {, then we should use getJSONObject() method."

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of a complete solution to this problem (yes, I know that this post died long ago...) :

If you want a `JSONObject`, then first get a `String` from the `result`:

```
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Then you can get your `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `JSONObject` like below:

```
String mJsonString = downloadFileFromInternet(urls[0]);

JSONObject jObject = null;
try {
    jObject = new JSONObject(mJsonString);
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

...

```
private String downloadFileFromInternet(String url)
{
    if(url == null /*|| url.isEmpty() == true*/)
        new IllegalArgumentException("url is empty/null");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try
    {
        url = urlEncode(url);
        URL link = new URL(url);
        inStream = link.openStream();
        int i;
        int total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        while((i=inStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            if(total >= (1024 * 1024))
            {
                return "";
            }
            total += i;
            sb.append(new String(buffer,0,i));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private String urlEncode(String url)
{
    if(url == null /*|| url.isEmpty() == true*/)
        return null;
    url = url.replace("[","");
    url = url.replace("]","");
    url = url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
    return url;
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Hi Apnologica.. in case any of the answers satiftied your need, please accept it so as to benefit others in reaching to correct answer easily. thanks

Answer (score 1):

1)String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
2)JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a JSONObject constructor to turn a String into a JSONObject:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If your api is response is a java object, then the string that you got from Outputstream should be in json string format such as

```
{\"name\":\"xyz\", \"age\":21}
```

. This can be converted to JSON object in many ways, out of which one way is to use google GSON library.
 `GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting();         Gson gson = builder.create(); <javaobject> = gson.fromJson(<outputString>, <Classofobject>.class);`

Answer (score 0):

One can do it without Gson also, using Jackson, which implements Json Tree Model.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(responseString);
```