# JAVA HTTPS get JSON from URL

Tags: java, json, https

I'm trying to receive the json of this url: https://usecryptos.com/jsonapi/ticker/BTC-USD It's accessible by browser, however, I haven't been successed, can someone post a code to do it?

Comment: Did you google before asking on SO?

Comment: how did you try to receive it? please post the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-json-object-from-a-http-response

Comment: No. This isn't a free coding service. _You_ post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying like this:

```
public static String getJSON(String url, int timeout) throws IOException {

    URL u = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    c.setUseCaches(false);
    c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    c.connect();
    int status = c.getResponseCode();

    switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `https` you should use the `HttpsUrlConnection` like this:

```
    URL u = new URL("https://blockchain.info/de/ticker");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }

    br.close();
    isr.close();
    is.close();
    conn.disconnect();
```