# Read json by url

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read [json](https://html2-f.scribdassets.com/7yt0rp2tkw2hbdil/pages/4-5eab67b634.jsonp) by url. This is my effort:

```
 public String getContentByUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        return json.toString();
    }
```

Throws

> A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 2 [character 3 line 1]

Also I tried `JSONPObject`, but it hasn't got such constructor. What do?

Comment: Well what does the response look like? Seems like it is not valid JSON.

Comment: @germi, http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ says it is a valid json.

Comment: Put the result of `IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` in a string and log it.

Comment: @Biffen, do you mean the problem is related to encoding?

Comment: @Tony I don't know what it could be, but encoding is a good guess (what made you choose UTF-8?). Logging the string is just a step in the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge and the [JSON API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)) there is only one `JSONObject` constructor that your try with a `String`.

In the API it says that the `String` source has to be:

> A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right
>   brace).

The typical usecase therefore is to request the page content and parse the result as a `JSONObject` via the constructor, instead of passing a complete URL. Which is already described in several posts on stackoverflow (e.g. [Get a JSON object from a HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-json-object-from-a-http-response))

EDIT:

I guess the http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ accepts the content of your URL as legit JSON is because it recognises the brackets (`[ ]`) as a `JSONArray`.

If you put your "JSON" into http://jsonlint.com/ for example it shows you pretty much why it can't be a `JSONObject`.