# How to get JSON from HTTP to Java object on Android

Tags: java, android, json, http

I want to get JSON from HTTP and parse it into an object in my Android app.
I've tried Spring Framework with AsyncTask, but everyone says it's deprecated.

So how can I make this happen, or does someone have a link to a tutorial for me?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-json-object-from-a-http-response

Comment: HttpClient and HttpGet ared both deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I would extend Denis proposal with this article and when to use given library.

First of all article from few months ago [JSON Libraries Performance Comparison](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/)

If you dont wanna read:

- Use Jackson library for **big** JSON data
- Use GSON for **small** JSON data ( Most of the requests are rather small )

Answer (score 1):

refer this, it will give you response in String, you can convert it in jsonObject

```
public static String postUrlResponse(String url,List<NameValuePair> urlParameters) 
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("URL : " + url);
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best library for parsing JSON is [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). 
[Here](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-introduction.jsp) is very helpful tutorials about this. According to [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-3/) article you can see Jackson is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question thanks everyone.

```
public static List<Events> getEvents() {

    List<Events> ret = new ArrayList<Events>();
    ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(context);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    // YOUR URL GOES HERE
    String getUrl = "http://example.nl/CALL.ashx?Onderdeel=Feeds&AuthToken=" + WWIBCore.AuthToken;
    HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(getUrl);
    try {
        response = http.execute(getMethod);

        // CONVERT RESPONSE TO STRING
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON ARRAY
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

        // ITERATE THROUGH AND RETRIEVE EVENTS FIELDS
        int n = ja.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // GET INDIVIDUAL JSON OBJECT FROM JSON ARRAY
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            // CONVERT DATA FIELDS TO EVENTS OBJECT
            Events e = new Events();
            e.setNaam(jo.getString(("Naam")));
            e.setContent(jo.getString("Content"));

            ret.add(e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pr.dismiss();
    return ret;
}
```