# I created an HttpURLConnection but how do I parse the data?

Tags: android, json, server, httprequest

I created an HttpURLConnection between a server. It is shown below

```
public class SimpleHTTPRequest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;
  OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
  BufferedReader rd  = null;
  StringBuilder sb = null;
  String line = null;


  try {
     URL serverAddress = new URL("myUrl");
      //set up out communications stuff
      connection = null;

      //Set up the initial connection
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.connect();


      //read the result from the server
      rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      sb = new StringBuilder();

      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
      {
          sb.append(line + '\n');
          System.out.println(sb.toString());

      }


  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
      //close the connection, set all objects to null
      connection.disconnect();
      rd = null;
      sb = null;
      wr = null;
      connection = null;
  }
  }
  }
```

After connecting to my server I get a response in this format, which is an HTML5 response.

```
event: data
data: {"target":1,"data":   {"text":"Home","number":0,"id":02123421,"likes":[],"newPost":true,"created":1458300896392,"edited":1458300896392},"type":"create"}
```

But how do I parse this information for instance lets say I want the "text" home to be set to my text view how do I specifiy?

Comment: Did you get json from server ?

Comment: What is an HTML5 response?

Comment: Its not json its html5, I am streaming data from my server so I used an httpURLrequest to get the data

Comment: An URLConnection for HTTP (RFC 2616) used to send and receive data over the web. Data may be of any type and length. This class may be used to send and receive streaming data whose length is not known in advance.

Comment: @eli its not about lenght or type but about well formated data.

Comment: Why is it not well formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the output in your server side? For example:@Produces

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getData() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet based on the format in your response is to use a JSON object as in this post:

[Get a JSON object from a HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-json-object-from-a-http-response)

Get your response as an `HTTPResponse` object, then create a new JSON object using

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Using JSON is easy. But its too much for me to re write here. Take a loog at the developer page for a good description: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Format your string to well formated JSONString first to get response like:

```
{data: {"event": "data", "target":1,"data":{"text":"Home","number":0,"id":02123421,"likes":[],"newPost":true,"created":1458300896392,"edited":1458300896392},"type":"create"}}
```

and just create a JSONObject from your JSONString like:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
   {
      sb.append(line);
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
   }
JSONObject data = null;
try {
   data = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
   //code in case variable line isnt well format json string
}
```

Why would you even want to send malformed data from server to client? It has to have a format in my opinion.

And then you could access anything with [JSONObject Android APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) (As Nick mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

To parse html, you can use the Jsoup library.

http://jsoup.org/

Use examples:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Comment: Have you used it before?

Comment: Yes. If you want to take a look how I use it in my project: https://github.com/lucEvent/newsup

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
   try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                    String target=jsonObject.optString("target");
                        JSONObject data=jsonObject.optJSONObject("data");
                        String text=data.optString("text");
                        int number=data.optInt("number");
                        //---
                        JSONArray likes=data.optJSONArray("likes");
                        for (int i=0;i<likes.length();i++){
                            JSONObject likeObj = likes.getJSONObject(i);
                            // If you have likes object you can pares here like
                            int rating=likeObj.optInt("rating");
                        }
                        String newPost=data.optString("newPost");
                        String created=data.optString("created");
                        String edited=data.optString("edited");
                    String type=jsonObject.optString("type");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```