# Java read json from HTTP body

Tags: java, html, json, httprequest

I want to crawl the data of the following link with a Java program.
The first page is no problem, but when I want to crawl the data of the next pages, there is the same source code as for page one.
The information which I need stands in an array in a JSON which comes in a response of a get request. You can see the settings and the response in [this](http://s22.postimg.org/8prp7758x/Bla_Bla_Response_Array.png) picture.

[This](https://www.blablacar.de/search?fn=frankfurt&tn=muenchen&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1&noredirect=1#search?fn=frankfurt&fc=50.1109221|8.6821267&fcc=DE&tn=muenchen&tc=48.1351253|11.5819806&tcc=DE&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=2) is the link for the page with the JSON.

I found posts like this: [Get a JSON object from a HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-json-object-from-a-http-response), but if I use the getContent() method I only get the content of the page, not the full HTTP Body.
I even tried the getEntity() method  and many more things but non of them worked.
Most other posts read JSON from pages that include the JSON in the source code, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java).
Any ideas how i could get the full JSON or better just the array?

Appreciate your help,
kind regards.

Comment: Finally found an answer for a Java application, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753737/read-full-content-of-a-web-page-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do, but I try to figure out. You want to grab this [page](https://www.blablacar.de/search?fn=frankfurt&tn=muenchen&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1&noredirect=1#search?fn=frankfurt&fc=50.1109221%7C8.6821267&fcc=DE&tn=muenchen&tc=48.1351253%7C11.5819806&tcc=DE&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=2) contents with all the results of this search "247  Mitfahrgelegenheiten von Frankfurt nach Muenchen" right?

If so, you cannot just do a simple HTTP Get of this page, since the web site has active contents that need to be interpreted and executed by a HMTL/CSS/JavaScript rendering engine, that is a browser or a Browser Developer Kit, like [WebKit](https://webkit.org/). Luckily there are several tools that helps you to do this, in several languages. The most simple is in JavaScript and it is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Getting that page is simple as doing in a `javascript` source file:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Of course, there is a small work to do, but PhantomJS has a lot of [examples](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/tree/master/examples) how to wait for page contents to load, executing javascript within and so getting the whole page contents as you see it in a real browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer loretoparisi. You are right, i try to read the full content of the website and use the data. I will look into PhantomJS and try to use it for my proposes.