# Read full content of a web page in Java

Tags: java, html

I want to crawl the whole content of the following link with a Java program. The first page is no problem, but when I want to crawl the data of the next pages, there is the same source code as for page one. Therefore a simple HTTP Get does not help at all.

[This](https://www.blablacar.de/search?fn=frankfurt&tn=muenchen&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1&noredirect=1#search?fn=frankfurt&fc=50.1109221|8.6821267&fcc=DE&tn=muenchen&tc=48.1351253|11.5819806&tcc=DE&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=2) is the link for the page I need to crawl.
The web site has active contents that need to be interpreted and executed by a HMTL/CSS/JavaScript rendering engine. Therefore I have a simple solution with PhantomJS, but it is sophisticated to run PhantomJS code in Java.

Is there any easier way to read the whole content of the page with Java code? I already searched for a solution, but could not find anything suitable.

Appreciate your help,
kind regards.

Comment: Could use an actual browser, and interface to it with WebDriver? Or consider the HTML5 browser included in JavaFX... ?

Comment: Try selenium? Sample: http://scraping.pro/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-with-java/

Comment: Be aware that the URL you have posted contains geographical coordinates. I don't know what they refer to but if they are personal information you may want to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Chrome network log (or a similar tool in any other browser) you can identify the XHR request that loads the actual data displayed on the page. I have removed some of the query parameters, but essentially the request looks like this:

```
GET https://www.blablacar.de/search_xhr?fn=frankfurt&fcc=DE&tn=muenchen&tcc=DE&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1&user_bridge=0&_=1461181945520
```

Helpfully, the query parameters look quite easy to understand. The `order=asc&limit=10&page=1` part looks like it would be easy to adjust to return your desired results. You could adjust the `page` parameter to crawl successive pages of data.

The response is JSON, for which there are a ton of libraries available.

Comment: If I crawl the url given by the XHR request and change the page numbers, I get all data I need.