# Get specific JSON attribute from a JSON/String file

Tags: java, json

I am sending a POST request to a server. The server responds with the following (JSON):

```
{"data":[      
{
  "password":"1234578566",
  "status":"processing"
}
],
 "status":200
}
```

This is my POST Method:

```
public static void sendPostRequest(String conversion) throws IOException, AuthenticationException {
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://url.com");

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(conversion));
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials =
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
httpPost.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(credentials, httpPost, null));

httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

client.close();
//     System.out.println(data); 
}
```

Please note the String "data" is the server responding with the JSON data above. Now, I am trying to get the password attribute from the data.

```
public static void getValue(String data) throws ParseException {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(data);

    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) object.get("data");
    JSONObject attribute = (JSONObject) array.get(0);
    JSONObject userData = (JSONObject) attribute.get("password");
    String result =  userData.toString();

    System.out.println(result);
}

Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (T) at position 0.
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I am getting this exception, but I wonder why? Have tried to change here and there but with no success.

These are my imports:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Print the value of data before trying to parse it, or use your debugger. It doesn't seem to contain the value you think it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are parsing response incorrectly. There are 2 things to be done here.

1)Make sure you obtain JSON data correctly from your response. You may follow this link [Get a JSON object from a HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-a-json-object-from-a-http-response) for getting stringified JSON data from your response.

2)Play around with your JSON to get specific values out of it. Your `getValue()` method could be used for that purpose with little modifications. I have made some changes to your method and here is the updated code for the same:

```
public static void getValue(String data) {
        try {
        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(data);       
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) responseObject.get("data");
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
        String result  = jsonObject.getString("password");

        System.out.println(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have tested it with your data and it working as per the expectation, printing 1234578566 over console.

Note : I have used org.json lib here and not simple json.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alien. Thanks for the reply. I have checked the link you provided, however for some reason my new JSONObject(data) asks for no arguments, doesn't let me pass data into it. I'm pretty sure I have all the libraries here, but I am double checking...

Comment: Hi Alien. I got it now. Thank you for your help and have a great day!

Comment: Hi leonev1,
Glad to see that it solved your problem. However you should also notice atleast who answered your question!